# Hide decimal point if no decimal digits present

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

```
var qtyMaskedTextEdit = new RepositoryItemTextEdit();
qtyMaskedTextEdit.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.Numeric;
qtyMaskedTextEdit.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
qtyMaskedTextEdit.Mask.EditMask = "#,###.##;(#,###.##)";
grid.RepositoryItems.Add(qtyMaskedTextEdit);
column.ColumnEdit = qtyMaskedTextEdit;
```

the following format: `"#,###.##;(#,###.##)"` shows 123 as 123. (with decimal point at the end)

How to get rid of this decimal point?

Comment: Try an just use "#,##"

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1:**
Creation of derived control worked for me with next modifications:

In the constructor:

```
CustomDisplayText += OnCustomDisplayText;
```

And after the subscription replace comma/dot sign with empty string:

```
private void OnCustomDisplayText(object sender, CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MaskType == DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.MaskType.Numeric &&
                MaskUseAsDisplayFormat &&
                !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.DisplayText) &&
                e.DisplayText.Last().ToString() == NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator)
            {
                e.DisplayText = e.DisplayText.Replace(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator, string.Empty);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

**MINUS:** in edit mode comma/dot is still visible

**SOLUTION 2:** I found that this problem occurs only with decimal type and this is .NET problem, not devexpress. With double, for example, there is no such problem.

There is a hack with dividing decimal on 1m (m = decimal) number after which trailing zeros disappear.

```
public static class NumberExtensions
{
    public static decimal RemoveTrailingZeros(this decimal number)
    {
        return (number / 1m);
    }
}
```

and then use it in your View Model or Model, e.g.

```
public decimal Number {get {return number.RemoveTrailingZeros(); }}
```

P.S. Still do not understand what the hell is happening after 1m dividing, here is the test of bytes before division and after:
[image: 1m division]